# How'd I create filter feature that works with multiple model on Django?

Tags: python, django, filter

So I have 2 models :

```
from django.db import models

class Profil(models.Model):
    nik     = models.IntegerField()
    nama    = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    tgl     = models.DateField()
    kelamin = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    namaibu = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    nikibu  = models.IntegerField()
    dusun  = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='Sumberejo')

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.nik}, {self.nama}, {self.namaibu}"
    
class Posyandu(models.Model):
    bulan  = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='Januari')
    nik = models.ForeignKey(Profil, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tb  = models.IntegerField()
    bb  = models.IntegerField()
    ll  = models.IntegerField()
    lk  = models.IntegerField()
    ket = models.CharField(max_length=20,)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.nik.nama}, {self.bulan}, {self.tb}, {self.bb}"
```

and display them as a table with this html

```
<table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>NIK</th>
                <th>Nama</th>
                <th>Tanggal Lahir</th>
                <th>Kelamin</th>
                <th>Nama Ibu</th>
                <th>Bulan</th>
                <th>TB</th>
                <th>BB</th>
                <th>LL</th>
                <th>LK</th>
                <th>Keterangan</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for profil in profils %}
            {% for posyandu in profil.posyandu_set.all %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ profil.nik }}</td>
                <td>{{ profil.nama }}</td>
                <td>{{ profil.tgl }}</td>
                <td>{{ profil.kelamin }}</td>
                <td>{{ profil.namaibu }}</td>
                <td>{{ posyandu.bulan }}</td>
                <td>{{ posyandu.tb }}</td>
                <td>{{ posyandu.bb }}</td>
                <td>{{ posyandu.ll }}</td>
                <td>{{ posyandu.lk }}</td>
                <td>{{ posyandu.ket }}</td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
            {% empty %}
            <tr>
                <td colspan="11">No data available</td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

aside from that I try to build a filter feature that able to filter what's displayed on the table based on months field (`bulan` field on Posyandu) with this views.py
this views.py

```
def riwayat(response):
    profils = Profil.objects.prefetch_related('posyandu_set')
    if response.method == 'POST':
        forms = BulanForm(response.POST)
        if forms.is_valid():
            bulan = forms.cleaned_data['bulan']
            profils = profils.filter(posyandu__bulan=bulan)
        
    else:
        forms = BulanForm()
    return render(response, 'all.html', {'profils': profils, 'forms' : forms})
```

and this form

```
class BulanForm(forms.Form):
    pilihanbulan = [
    ('Januari', 'Januari'),
    ('Februari', 'Februari'),
    ('Maret', 'Maret'),
    ('April', 'April'),
    ('Mei', 'Mei'),
    ('Juni', 'Juni'),
    ('Juli', 'Juli'),
    ('Agustus', 'Agustus'),
    ('September', 'September'),
    ('Oktober', 'Oktober'),
    ('November', 'November'),
    ('Desember', 'Desember'),
]

    bulan = forms.ChoiceField(
        required = True,
        widget = forms.Select,
        choices = pilihanbulan,
        label = 'Posyandu Bulan'

    )
```

The filter works, but not correctly, and by that I means it did filter and shows the data based on the months choosen by user, but other **Posyandu** data that is owned by same **Profil** is also displayed.
For example, Leonardo has **Posyandu** data on January and June. When I filter the data to display on **Januari**, somehow Leonardo's data on **June** is also being displayed. Maybe this explanation is still lacking, please refer to this screenshot for more context [https://i.imgur.com/XbvSYMz.png]

I conclude that the program is displaying all `Posyandu` objects owned by `Profil` that contains the selected month. So if Person A have `Posyandu` data on Januari, March, and September, and user choose to filter based on month Janury, the program will display all Person A's Posyandu data because Person A have Posyandu's data on January.

I want my filter to display only the selected month. How'd I do that?

I'm sorry if my question is confusing, as english is not my native language. And thank you for reading this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to filter the prefetch object as well:

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch


def riwayat(response):
    profils = Profil.objects.prefetch_related('posyandu_set')
    if response.method == 'POST':
        forms = BulanForm(response.POST)
        if forms.is_valid():
            bulan = forms.cleaned_data['bulan']
            profils = Profil.objects.prefetch_related(
                Prefetch('posyandu_set', Posyandu.objects.filter(bulan=bulan))
            ).filter(posyandu__bulan=bulan)

    else:
        forms = BulanForm()
    return render(response, 'all.html', {'profils': profils, 'forms': forms})
```

This will thus not only filter the `Profil` object such that it only takes `Profil`s with a related `Posyandu` that has the correct `bulan`, but also filter the set of related `Posyandu` objects, and thus only these will end up on the `.posyandu_set`s. of the retrieved `Profil`.